# Trying to search for file in a folder

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to create my first VBS script and I'm lost. I need to be able to search for a specific text  within 4 network paths. Basically this is 4 separate LOG files that only hold text files, no sub-directories or anything.  I would like if the text was found in whichever network path it would only bring that path up and not allow the rest to come up. The name of the text file should be user input driven.

Is there anyone who could point me in the right direction? Or help me out? I was able to open up the network path but not sure how to do the rest: Here is what I have so far: The code works.. but I have to be very specific.. I would like to only type "1234" then it finds that file, however the filename is always generated randomly, etc.. "1234-02304-923734.txt" or "1234-932987-973294" so I only need to search for the first 1234 but I won't know the rest. The way I do it now is open explore.exe then go to that path then do a search and it will look for it.

```
Dim Input
Input = InputBox("Enter beginning filename") 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.FolderExists("\\servername\c$\Program Files (x86)\LOGS\")       Then
If objFSO.FileExists("\\servername\c$\Program Files (x86)\LOGS\"&       Input) Then
        Wscript.Echo "Folder and file exist"
    Else
        Wscript.Echo "Folder exists, file doesn't"
    End If
Else
    Wscript.Echo "Folder does not exist"
End If
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

swstrau118,
I would like to help you understand your approach. First, you must recurse each subfolder within your Logs folder. You will then compare each file found with the file from the user input. Once you find a file, you can store the location within a variable until the search is complete and then return the locations back to the user.
I have found a useful link, not in VB script, but one I beleive you can follow. 
If you have trouble, perhaps asking a specific question about the code.

Hint, bringin each file name, absent the extention, will allow you to compare the strings for a quick match.

Here is the tip I mentioned, not in vb script, but along the lines of what you are needing.
http://www.dotnetperls.com/recursive-file-directory-vbnet
This is a vb script, though probably visual basic proper and not script.
http://www.ammara.com/access_image_faq/recursive_folder_search.html
Shows how to handle the recurse.

Comment: Would this work even If I'm only searching for 1 file out of the 4 network paths?

Comment: Yes, as I understand your problem, the 4 paths reside under one common folder. I would suggest recursing all folders below the common folder, and avoid adding them as an array.

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive function. When it comes across a folder it calls itself.

```
Sub GenerateFullHotkeyInFolder(Fldr) 
    on error resume next 
    set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Dict=CreateDictionary()
    Set FldrItems=Fldr.Items
    For Each oFile in FldrItems
        With oFile
            If .IsFileSystem = true And .IsLink = true And .Type <> "Shortcut to MS-DOS Program" then
                set lnk = .GetLink 
                If lnk.hotkey <> 0 then 
                    Set fsop = fso.GetFile(.Path)
                    LnkName = "<b>" & fso.GetBaseName(fso.GetFile(.Path)) & "</b><br>" & fsop.ParentFolder.path & "\" & fso.GetBaseName(fso.GetFile(.Path)) & "." & fso.GetExtensionName(fso.GetFile(.Path))
                    HK=Dict.Item(lnk.hotkey AND 255)
                    If HK = "" then HK = "A reserved or OEM specific key"
                    Modkey =""
                    If (lnk.hotkey And 256) = 256 then Modkey = "Shift + "
                    If (lnk.hotkey And 512) = 512 then Modkey = ModKey + "Ctrl + "
                    If (lnk.hotkey And 1024) = 1024 then Modkey = ModKey + "Alt + "
                    If (lnk.hotkey And 2048) = 2048 then Modkey = ModKey + "Winkey + "
                    DiagVar = DiagVar & "<tr><td><b>" & ModKey & " " & HK & "</b></td><td><a class=TblURL  onmouseover='MakeRed()' onmouseout='MakeBlack()' onclick='FindShortcut(" & Chr(34) & .path & Chr(34) & ")'>" & LnkName  & "</a>" & "</td><td><a class=TblURL onmouseover='MakeRed()' onmouseout='MakeBlack()' onclick='FindShortcut(" & Chr(34) & lnk.path & Chr(34) & ")'>" & lnk.path & "</a></td></tr>" & vbcrlf
                End If 
            ElseIf .IsFileSystem = true And .IsFolder = true then
                GenerateFullHotkeyInFolder(.GetFolder)
            End If          
        End With
    Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple tips.

1. You can create an array to hold each network path you want to search.
2. If you just want to test the *start* of the filename, use the `Left()` function on each file's name and compare that against your input.

   ```
   ' Create an array to hold each path to search...
   Paths = Array("\\server1\c$", _
                 "\\server2\c$", _
                 "\\server3\c$", _
                 "\\server4\c$")

   ' Check each file in each path...
   For Each Path In Paths
       For Each File In objFSO.GetFolder(Path).Files
           If StrComp(Left(File.Name, Len(Input)), Input, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

               WScript.Echo "Found " & File.Name & " at " & Path & "."

           End If
       Next
   Next
   ```